# Is there an alternative function other than rdpcap to read pcap files using scapy?

Tags: python, wireshark, scapy, pcap, pcap-ng

I am trying to read the pcap files using Scapy in Python. I have a set of pcap/pcapng files. Few of them work just fine when `rdpcap` is used. Few of them throw this error.

```
Exception has occurred: OSError
[Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

I tried using `PcapReader()` instead of `rdpcap` but it throws the same error too. I am not sure if the files are corrupted or if the files are too large to be read. Although, these files work completely fine when I open through Wireshark. Can somebody suggest me an alternative option?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should post the code you're using, version you're using... there are a lot of tools that can do this but let's first figure out why it's not working.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I figured why it was not working. I had some issues while using the directory.